# Laravel 5.8 | Test JSON response like assertJsonMessage?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to test the json test response contain different values, in this case error messages, like so:

```
public function testFieldsAreRequired()
{
    $this->postJson('/posts', [])
        ->assertStatus(422)
        ->assertJsonValidationErrors([
            'name',
            'email',
            'date_of_birth',
        ])
        ->assertJsonFragment([
            'The name field is required.'
        ])
        ->assertJsonFragment([
            'The email field is required.'
        ])
        ->assertJsonFragment([
            'The date of birth field is required.'
        ]);
}
```

This approach is not very efficient. I'm looking for an approach, like so:

```
.....
->assertJsonMessage([
    'The name field is required.',
    'The email field is required.',
    'The date of birth field is required',
]);
```

Like above, I don't need to specify keys and can specfiy different values in one array. So it's very efficient and manageable.

But `assertJsonMessage` is a protected method, so I'm not sure about original design and using this approach.

Comment: So you don't want to test that specific keys are failing, you just want to test that the certain error messages are in the response?

Comment: You're right, not really the keys, but the error messages.